# В файлах с расширением js перестала автоматически закрываться скобка (редактор vs code)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Раньше при вводе левой скобки автоматически дописывалась и правая скобка

Comment: `editor.autoClosingBrackets` - см. через Ctrl+F, т.к. помимо общего значения этой настройки есть возможность ее переопределения для отдельных языков.

Comment: @yar85 поставил значение "always" у этого ключа, но всё равно не работает

Comment: Самый прикол в том, что такая проблема только с js файлами в остальных всё нормально

Comment: Оказывается проблема была из-за расширения copilot, отключил и всё заработало

Comment: У расширения могут быть свои настройки относительно скобок (стоит поискать их, если решение  отключением не полностью устраивает).

Answer (score 2):

Оказывается проблема была из-за расширения copilot, отключил и всё заработало